# Error in placing values in an object class inside an ArrayList

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I'm trying to create a table(2d)in which each cell consist of a value and key(created an object for this) but i'm having trouble in placing a value to the object from the `ArrayList`.

> Incompatible types: `String` cannot be converted to `int`

```
public static void Con(){
ArrayList<Content> arrList1 = new ArrayList<Content>();
ArrayList<ArrayList> arrList2 = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();

//Content yeah = new Content("asdfas","asdfasdf");
for(Content a: arrList1)
//arrList1.add(Content a = new Content("asdf","fasd"));
arrList1.add("oh","yeah");
//arrList1.ge

}
```

Here is the object class

```
public class Content extends Object{
    private String key;
    private String value;   
    private String keyVal;

    public Content (String key, String value) {

        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getKey() {

        return key; 
    }

    public String getValue() {

        return value;   
    }

    public String getKeyValue(){
        return key+value;
    }

    public void display(){      
        System.out.println(this.key+","+this.value);
    }

}
```

Comment: p.s  it says incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int

Answer (score 0):

I already figured it out. I used:

```
arrList1.add(new Content("9","9"));
```

Sorry for the trouble